# Karma test runner is slower than it should be

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Basically i am test driving my knockout viewmodels in durandal.

I am up to 80 tests and the total running time is 58 seconds.

When i watched the video at : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mHjJ4xf_K0#t=577
the guy runs over 1500 tests in under 3 seconds.

*It would seem that i must be doing something very wrong.*

Here is an example of one of my tests just to give some context to what i am doing.

```
define(["doubles/TestCart", "komapping", "generators/BenefitGenerator"],
function (vm, mapping, benefitGenerator)
{
    describe('When retrieving the cart data', function ()
    {
        var benefitOne = benefitGenerator.generateBenefit();
        var benefitTwo = benefitGenerator.generateBenefit({ Status: 1 });
        var benefitThree = benefitGenerator.generateBenefit({ Status: 2 });

        beforeEach(function (done)
        {
            vm.Reset();

            $.mockjax({
                url: "*/api/Benefits",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "get",
                responseText: [
                    benefitOne,
                    benefitTwo,
                    benefitThree
                ],
                onAfterComplete: function () { done(); }
            });

            //Act
            vm.refresh();
        });

        it('should have the correct benefits', function ()
        {
            expect(vm.allBenefits()[0].Id()).toEqual(benefitOne.Id);
            expect(vm.allBenefits()[1].Id()).toEqual(benefitTwo.Id);
            expect(vm.allBenefits()[2].Id()).toEqual(benefitThree.Id);
        });

        it('should have the correct cart count', function () {
            expect(vm.cartBenefitCount()).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
});
```

Note, i do not have the browser minimised and i cant yet quite use the new jasmine 2.1 beforeAll rather than beforeEach (although in tests this will half my run time).

==Addendum==

I have removed all the implementation out of the test, i just have an empty describe with no before each and then two empty its. Each it is taking half a second to run. It seems it is not my test itself but the config somehow, i'll keep looking.

==Addendum 2==

I have now got this down to 20 seconds. The issue was that i had a test with no "describe" it was running this test after each of its in all of the other tests. My bottleneck now seems to be mockjax which takes 500ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so now i have the tests down to 0.2 seconds, quite an improvment i am sure you agree.

Steps to fix this for me were 2 fold:

Step 1) I had a test without a describe, karma was running this test after every single "it" for every test. 
Once i added the describe my run time went down to 20 seconds. This test with the missing describe was using mockjax which leads me to...

Step 2)
Mockjax has a default response time of 500ms. This was costing me about 20 seconds. I set the config to `$.mockjaxSettings.responseTime = 1; //1ms` and now the run time is down to 0.23 seconds.

Hopefully this will help others.